# siunitx for Monetary Units

Tags: siunitx

Can I use the `siunitx` package for monetary units (not SI units)? I have a lot of big dollar amounts that I would like to auto-round.
E.g., I want `1075222995501` to read as `1.075T$`.

I tried the following without success:

```
\SI[
    fixed-exponent=3,
    round-precision=3,
    round-mode=places
]{1075222995501}[\$]
```

Comment: If you replace millions, billions, and trillions of $ with "M$", "G$", and "T$" (for mega, giga, and tera, right?), you've pretty much guaranteed that nobody will be able to follow what you're saying, or even bother to figure out what you're saying... What is wrong, incidentally, with writing `1.075\times10^{12}\$`?

Comment: OK, let's say I wanted it to read `1.075 trillion $`, instead. Is there a way to do _this_ automatically via siunitx?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what a use case may be. (E.g., what's keeping you from just writing `1.075 trillion \$`?) Hence, please do provide your own use case. Thanks.

Comment: For integers the numspell package compiles `\numspell[12]{2}` to "two trillion". The fmtcount package compiles `\newcounter{blub}\setcounter{blub}{20000}\numberstring{blub}` to "two thousand", but higher numbers are quickly out of range.